# How to add JAX-B APIs during Citrus setup?

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, citrus-framework

I'm evaluating Citrus framework and I have problems with the setup. Following the documentation, I ran `mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=com.consol.citrus.mvn:citrus`, selected option "Citrus quickstart project" and defined values for groupId and the others. Then I ran `mvn clean verify` and it failed with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException`. It seems that not all dependencies are included in the archetype, or that I need to choose another archetype. What is the recommended way to add the JAX-B APIs in my case? Should I use another archetype maybe?

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise amd64; JDK: RedHat OpenJDK 11; IDE: VS Code 1.50.1; Maven: 3.6.3; Citrus version: 2.7.3

Comment: I have added Maven dependencies for JAX-B and could successfully run a `mvn test`. However, the integration-tests still fail with a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my Citrus framework setup on Java 11 by adding the JAXB Maven dependencies javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api and org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime. Plus, I have upgraded maven-failsafe-plugin to version 2.22.2. Now, I can run `mvn clean verify` without errors and get build success.

See also [Java: How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/java-how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexceptio) and https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/java9.html